# How to compile and run my Maven unit tests for a Java 11, while having my code compiled for an older version of Java 8

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit, jenkins

I want to use Java 11 syntax in my unit tests, but my 'main' code needs to be compiled for Java 8 since my production environment only has JDK 8 installed.

Is there a way of doing this with the maven-compiler-plugin?
My Jenkins server has Java 11 installed.

I will accept the risk that I can accidental use Java 11 specific functionality in my production code.

Comment: +1 Note that it is a bit risky to just set the source language version. You might accidentally use Java 8 API and the compiler will not complain. So to be safe, you'd need to compile with the Java7 class libraries, too (which probably leads to complex maven profiles...)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Maven compile and testCompile goals are different. And Maven even has parameters for testCompile: testTarget and testSource. So:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <testSource>1.8</testSource>
        <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: There's a nice example of how to use this method and keep your code safe (= not using Java 8 APIs by mistake) under https://gist.github.com/aslakknutsen/9648594

Comment: @blalasaadri yeah, nice addition.

Comment: @blalasaadri , I like your answer as well

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more terse version of mkrakhin's answer
You can set the [source](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html#source), [target](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#target), [testSource](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html#testSource) and [testTarget](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html#testTarget) :

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <maven.compiler.testSource>11</maven.compiler.testSource>
    <maven.compiler.testTarget>11</maven.compiler.testTarget>
  </properties>
</project>
```